# Image resize not working on PhotoImage in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I am trying to make a code to display smaller wind vector images over a Map background image. The only problem is that the wind vectors are larger than required and I want to scale them down. I tried `subsample()` but it doesn't work for some reason and the image remains of same size.

The preliminary code for this is as follows;

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Click me!")
def next_image(event):
    #toggle between image2 and image3
    global toggle_flag
    global x, y, photo2, photo3
    if toggle_flag == TRUE:
        # display photo2, same center x, y
        canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo2)
        toggle_flag = False
    else:
        canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo3)
        toggle_flag = True

toggle_flag = True
# pick three GIF image files you have in your working directory
# image1 is larger than image2 and image3
image1 = "Map.png"
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
image2 = "icons8-wind-speed-43-47-50.png"
photo2 = PhotoImage(file=image2)
photo2.subsample(50)
image3 = "icons8-wind-speed-103-107-50.png"
photo3 = PhotoImage(file=image3)
photo3.subsample(50)
# make canvas the size of image1/photo1
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack()
# display photo1, x, y is center (anchor=CENTER is default)
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1)
canvas1.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)  # bind left mouse click
root.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10 and the default tkinter package.
Please help.

The output looks like this;
[image: Output image for given code, showing a wind barb vector over the map.]

Comment: `subsample` does not change the original `PhotoImage`, as the docstring says, it returns a new `PhotoImage`. So I think you need to do `photo = photo.subsample(50)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I came to accept. Thanks to j_4321.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Click me!")
def next_image(event):
    #toggle between image2 and image3
    global toggle_flag
    global x, y, photo2, photo3
    if toggle_flag == TRUE:
        # display photo2, same center x, y
        canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo2)
        toggle_flag = False
    else:
        canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo3)
        toggle_flag = True

toggle_flag = True
# pick three GIF image files you have in your working directory
# image1 is larger than image2 and image3
image1 = "Map.png"
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
image2 = "icons8-wind-speed-43-47-50.png"
photo2 = PhotoImage(file=image2)
photo2 = photo2.subsample(50)
image3 = "icons8-wind-speed-103-107-50.png"
photo3 = PhotoImage(file=image3)
photo3 = photo3.subsample(50)
# make canvas the size of image1/photo1
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack()
# display photo1, x, y is center (anchor=CENTER is default)
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1)
canvas1.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)  # bind left mouse click
root.mainloop()
```